# On Steenrod's realization of cycles problem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cobordism

There is old problem of realization homology classes of (closed) manifold $M^n$ by fundamental classes of its submanifolds. Partially it was solved by René Thom in his "Quelques propriétés globales des variétés différentiables", according to his results, every homology class $z_k$ with $k<6$ is realizable by some submanifold. It seems to be well known, that this result is also true for $k=6$. Is there some articles, where one could find such a proof?

P.S. I'm sorry for repeating this question again, but I did not find any proper answers there or anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

Rudyak's article [*The problem of realization of homology classes from Poincare up to the present*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0084717) seems to be a good starting point.

The original paper is Thom's [*Quelques propriétés globales des variétés différentiables*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/thomcob.pdf).

Comment: If you can't access Rudyak's article through the "official" link, here's another one: https://www.docdroid.net/B2L0lGq/rudyak-the-problem-of-realization-of-homology-classes-from-poincar-to-the-present.pdf.html